# Indexing in Polybius cipher produce error in python

Tags: python, indexing, cryptography

I'm making a polybius cipher. So I made a table to convert with the keyword tomato

```
alp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
s = str(input("keyword: "))

for i in s: 
    alp = alp.replace(i,"")
    
s2 = "".join(dict.fromkeys(s))
    
jaa = s2+alp
x = list(jaa)


array = np.array(x)
re = np.reshape(array,(6,6))

dt = pd.DataFrame(re)
dt.columns = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dt.index = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dt


    1   2   3   4   5   6
1   t   o   m   a   b   c
2   d   e   f   g   h   i
3   j   k   l   n   p   q
4   r   s   u   v   w   x
5   y   z   0   1   2   3
6   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

I want to translate poly with this code

```
poly = '25 34 14 12 35 22 43 21 25 34 24  33 51  23 12 25 13 34 22'    
a = poly.split(" ")
for i in range (len(a)):
    hur = a[i]
    w = dt._get_value(hur[0],hur[1])
    print(w)
```

But, keyerror : '5'. I've tried to get value with (2,5), the output is good, but can't run it with the indexing. Which part is missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's because hur[0] and hur[1] is a string, not an integer.
You need to do:

```
for hur in a:
    w = dt._get_value(int(hur[0]),int(hur[1]))
    print(w, end="")  # end="" will print it as one text instead of over multiple lines
```

Note that your poly has a double space which will mess up the split method.